# What is a Vector Cache?

Tags: database, optimization

I ran across [Twitter's Real-time Reporting Project Rainbird](http://www.slideshare.net/kevinweil/rainbird-realtime-analytics-at-twitter-strata-2011) and read their [High Scalability Profile](http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster), and got excited about the "vector cache".  I get what it is from a high level, but how would you start implementing something like this (and what is it exactly)?  I can't find much on google.

What are the components of a Vector Cache?

Comment: Perhaps he meant http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_15.html (nothing to be excited about IMO).

Comment: and, if @Jaroslav is correct, this is similar to being able to access an indexed column in a database table faster than a non-indexed one.